# Did Shimshon sleep with the harlot when he Came to Gaza

Tags: shoftim--book-of, shimshon-samson

In the book of Judges Chapter 16 it says:
1And Samson went to Gaza, and saw there a harlot, and came to her.      אוַיֵּלֶךְ שִׁמְשׁוֹן עַזָּתָה וַיַּרְא שָׁם אִשָּׁה זוֹנָה וַיָּבֹא אֵלֶיהָ:

When it says he came to her does it mean that he slept with her?
And if not then why does it even have to mention that she was a harlot? Or for that matter that "he came to her"

Answer (score 2):

The Gemoro [Sotah 9b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=9b&format=text) says

> תחילת קלקולו בעזה דכתיב (שופטים טז, א) וילך שמשון עזתה וירא שם אשה
>   זונה וגו' לפיכך לקה בעזה דכתיב (שופטים טז, כא)) ויורידו אותו עזתה
>
> The beginning of his destruction occurred in Gaza as it says in Judges
>   16 (1) “And Samson went to Gaza, and saw there a harlot, and etc.”,
>   therefore he was afflicted in Gaza as it says [Judges 16
>   (21)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15824#showrashi=true)
>   “and they brought him down to Gaza, (and bound him with fetters of
>   brass;)”.

Rashi on the Gemoro says that the earlier encounter with a woman in Timnah [Judges 14 (1)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15822#showrashi=true) did not involve immorality like this one in Gaza did.

Comment: How was that the begining of his destruction?

Comment: Insofar as he sinned. That brought on his destruction.

Comment: That's an interesting point. So his first woman was totally kosher in that case